# Existence of periodic solution of a 2nd order homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the equation
$x''(t) + α(t)x(t) = 0$
where $α$ is a continuous function on $−∞ < t < ∞$ which is of period $τ$. Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be the
linearly independent solutions satisfying

$x_1(t_0)=1=x'_2(t_0)$ and $x'_1(t_0)=x_2(t_0)$.

1) Show that $W[x_1, x_2](t) = 1$ for all $t$.

2) Show that there is at least one non-trivial solution $x$ of period $τ$ if, and only if,
$x_1(τ ) = 1 = x'_2(τ )$, $x_2(τ ) = x'_1(τ ) = 0 .$

The first part was easy. The Wronskian of $x_1$ and $x_2$ at $t_0$ is 1. And since the coefficient of $x'$ in the ODE is $0$, by Abel's theorem, the Wronskian is identically $1$.
But I have no clue how to do the second part.  Assuming $x$ is a periodic solution of period $\tau$, I was only able to show that $x_1(t_0+\tau)+x'_2(t_0+\tau)=2$.

Any hint would be very much appreciated. Thank you.